# How can an API call be handled completely on the server side without the client seeing it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know if the following is possible and if it is please guide me in the right path.

My site is `x.com` and when a user submits a form on my site an API call is made to `y.com` which returns a `JS` hash (yeah very outdated, I know).

You can see the call to `y.com` being made in FireBug with returned params. Problem is that Adblocker Plus is intercepting this content and blocking it from view. (Not good (displaying a message about ad blocker is not a solution (In this case the user is actually expecting the ad)))

Is it possible to have my server make the request to `y.com` server (without the user's client being aware) get the response on my server side, and then finally generate the page and with the response content in the body, and lastly render to client?

Comment: It's definitely possible. Your server might have to be configured though to allow for such requests, and you'll want a library that helps make HTTP requests. I'm not a Ruby/Rails developer, but search for "Ruby HTTP Client". It looks like there are at least ten such libraries, including one named "HTTPClient".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely possible. You could define an endpoint on your local rails app (x.com) and submit the form to that endpoint. Then use an HTTP library, I prefer [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client), to then submit the form to y.com.